# Running jersey 2 server using jetty 9

Tags: eclipse, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty

I have been struggling for many hours on trying to deploy a simple HelloWorld webservice written in java on a windows 7 (later ill need on linux) pc.

Most of the examples I found (from general places, and others questetions on stackoverflow) didn't work or used deprecated versions of jersey and other librarys.

My goal, is to write a webservice in java, where coding it should be easy and so does deploying it. It doesn't need to suuport anything special regarding the amount of request running and performance (my requirements are minimum)

Frommy research, I have come to believe the use of jersey with embeded netty web service should anser what I was looking for (if someone knows better, I would also like to hear about it, tough it isn't my main problem in this questetion but might just be an alternative solution)

I have came across this eaxmple:

[jersey2-jetty-example](https://github.com/edomingues/jersey2-jetty-example)

It gives you a working project with the dependencies needed from maven to run jersey and jetty embedded server (which can be run as a standalone jar which is exactly the kind of easy deploy im looking for)

I cloned the example and got everything running. I had problems importing it to eclipse, so I used the following command on the example folder:

mvn -DoutputDirectory=./lib dependency:copy-dependencies

which will give you a copy of the lib folder of the deps from maven needed,
then I created a java project with this lib folder in the build path and same source code as the sample, and all worked good.
The problem occurs when I try to take this java project and export it as an runnable jar (with the source files included option !).
I can then use java -jar to run the service, but when I try to access it from the browser (same as used in when I run it from eclipse), it never works, im always getting error 404 for the same routes that worked a second ago when running from eclipse. I couldn't figure out whats the source of the problem or what eclipse does differently that makes it behave in a different fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason the jar didn't work while in eclipse it did work, it was because of a duplicate jar that I was importing the caused the problem. The jars I got from maven in the git sample had 2 duplicate jars called hamcrest-all and hamcrest-core. removing one of them from the project build path fixed the problem.

If someone can answer the other open ended questetion that I asked, which is if using jersey and jetty like this is the best solution for my requirments I will be happy to hear about it